# Why comparison return an integer instead of a boolean?

Tags: python

I was testing some piece of code

```
True = 2
print 1 - (1 == 1)
print True == (1 == 1)
```

Then I was expecting:

```
-1
True
```

But I got this instead:

```
0
False
```

So, I did what any python programmer would do: disassemble it.

```
def f():
    True = 2
    print 1 - (1 == 1)
    print True == (1 == 1)

2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
            3 STORE_FAST               0 (True)

3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            9 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           15 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           18 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
           19 PRINT_ITEM          
           20 PRINT_NEWLINE       

4          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (True)
           24 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           27 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           30 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           33 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           36 PRINT_ITEM          
           37 PRINT_NEWLINE       
           38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           41 RETURN_VALUE
```

Then it was a bit clear, is using the `COMPARE_OP (==)`. Witch should return a boolean but it appears that it returns a integer instead. Any ideas why?

**Edit:**

In short the lesson learned: Changing the values of True or False doesn't change how the boolean logic is represented behind the scene.

Comment: In python 3 this has been fixed, `True` and `False` are keywords now,  you can't assign anything to them.

Comment: However, `3>> True == 1`
`True`

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/

Comment: As a side note, the _actual_ lesson here is that names have nothing to do with values. Given `ten=42`, would you expect `9+1` to return `42`?

Comment: @thg435 No, I would expect `ten == (9 + 1)` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your misunderstanding was in thinking that treating `True` like a variable would actually change the results of boolean operations.  It doesn't.  `True` is used by default to respresent, well, boolean truth, but it loses that functionality when you changes its value.  However, that doesn't change the rules for how booleans are treated with respect to integers.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `False` and `True` have the equivalent values of `0` and `1` respectively. Also, `__eq__()` can return any object it likes; it just so happens that for built-in types it returns `bool` instances.

Answer (score 3):

I think Ashwini Chaudhary's comment on the question is key to understanding why things are not working the way you expect.

Boolean operators in Python generally return `bool(1)` or `bool(0)`, not the values of `True` or `False`. In Python 2, `True` and `False` are just names that are bound to `bool(1)` and `bool(0)` respectively. If you rebind the name `True` to a different value (such as `2`), it doesn't change the return value from the comparisons, which remains `bool(1)`.

In Python 3, this issue is sidestepped by making the names `True` and `False` into keywords, so they cannot be rebound to new values.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> True = 2
```

Here you assign `2` to `True`. So now `True` in the module's scope is actually `2`:

```
>>> print(True)
2
```

---

`1 == 1` is `True`. `True` is [equal to `1`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

```
>>> 1 - (1 == 1)
0
```

You could ask why it isn't `2`, as above. Well, `True` variable is equal to `2` in the module's scope, and `(1==1)` just returns the reference (tag) to real `True`. So `1==1` is a real `True` which is equal to `1`, so `1 - (1 == 1)` is equal to `0`.

---

```
>>> print True == (1 == 1)
False
```

Here `1 == 1` again return reference to real `True`. But the `True` in the first part of the expression is from the module's scope, so it is actually `2`. So this expression is effectively `2 == (True)` which equals to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

When you minus and integer from a boolean, its integer representation is used; as they are subclasses of `int`.

`int(True)` is `1`, and so you have `1-1` which is `0`.

Also, `-1` is a boolean `True` (its not a "Falsey" value) so expecting that as an answer would not have been accurate either:

```
>>> -1 == True
False
>>> -1 == False
False
>>> bool(-1)
True
```